# How can i add Control for dynamic ContextMenu (RightClick)

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, contextmenu

im working on code-editor(winforms) and im just wondering how can i add controls for contextmenu . and i dont use designer from the start.

now my current code for rightclick event was:

```
private void rtb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {

            MenuItem[] menuItems = new MenuItem[] { new MenuItem("Cut"), new MenuItem("Copy"), new MenuItem("Paste") };

            ContextMenu rightcontext = new ContextMenu(menuItems);

            int xOffset = Cursor.Position.X - Dte.ActiveForm.Location.X;
            int yOffset = Cursor.Position.Y - Dte.ActiveForm.Location.Y;

            rightcontext.Show(Dte.ActiveForm, new Point(xOffset, yOffset));

        }
    }
```

which already worked now . but the problem was how to add controls on list on contextmenu .

particularly the Cut, Copy and Paste .

like code something like this?

```
if (rightcontext.menuItems.SelectedItems == "Cut")
{
    rtb.Cut()
}
```

something like that but ofcourse it wouldnt work coz contextmenu doesnt have .SelectedItems function .

so my problem was how to add control on those list . pls help :/ thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to handle clicking on menu items? To do that you have to add event handler to your menu items.

```
//create menu items with cunstructor that takes 2 arguemtns (string, and event handler)

MenuItem[] menuItems = new MenuItem[] { new MenuItem("Cut", new System.EventHandler(this.CutMenuItemClick)), 
                                        new MenuItem("Copy", new System.EventHandler(this.CopyMenuItemClick)),
                                        new MenuItem("Paste", new System.EventHandler(this.PasteMenuItemClick)) };
```

and create all three events like that:

```
private void CutMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtb.Cut();
}
```

Comment: +1 sir since you also got same result as boss Mehran .really thanks for the help sir!

Comment: ill accept it sorry ... simplicity of code is the best still thanks :P

Answer (score 1):

When creating your MenuItem's, create them outside of the new MenuItem[]{} constructor first.
Then for each menu item use the event Click.

Example:

```
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Test");
        item.Click += item_Click;

        //Then your code..
        MenuItem[] menuItems = new MenuItem[] { item /*Etc...*/ };
    }

    void item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

just define event handler for the menu items

here you go :

```
    ContextMenu rightcontext;

    private void rtb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {

            MenuItem[] menuItems = new MenuItem[] { new MenuItem("Cut"), new MenuItem("Copy"), new MenuItem("Paste") };

            rightcontext = new ContextMenu(menuItems);

            rightcontext.MenuItems[0].Click += contextMenuItemClick;
            rightcontext.MenuItems[1].Click += contextMenuItemClick;
            rightcontext.MenuItems[2].Click += contextMenuItemClick;

            int xOffset = Cursor.Position.X - Dte.ActiveForm.Location.X;
            int yOffset = Cursor.Position.Y - Dte.ActiveForm.Location.Y;

            rightcontext.Show(Dte.ActiveForm, new Point(xOffset, yOffset));

        }
    }

    private void contextMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem m = (MenuItem)(sender);
        if (m.Text.ToLower() == "copy")
        {
            // Some Code
        }
    }
```